# WooCommerce Rest API: Create product with images

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to add products using the WooCommerce .Net Rest API. Everything is working fine except for my images. I'm not sure how to add them with PHP.

I get my products from another source that gives me all the images separated by a comma. When I retrieve them I make an array out of it like this:

```
    $afbeeldingen = explode(",", $_POST['afbeeldingen']) ;
```

For the following part I'm lost.. I have to put the images urls inside the 'images' array like the way it is shown below. I was thinking about using some foreach loop but I'm not sure how to make this work.

```
$prod_data = [
    'name'              => $_POST['merk'] . ' ' . $_POST['model'] . ' ' . $_POST['type'],
    'type'              => 'simple',
    'sku'               => $_POST['voertuignr_hexon'],
    'regular_price'     => $_POST['verkoopprijs_particulier'],
    'description'       => $_POST['opmerkingen'],
    'images'            => [
        [
            'src' => image1
        ],
        [
            'src' => image2
        ]
    ]
];
```

I would appreciate any help that I can get with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through each element of `afbeeldingen` and create an array for each with the key `src` then push them to another array that stores all the src elements. Below code should do that.

```
$images = array();
$size = count($afbeeldingen);
for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) { 
    $img = array("src" => $afbeeldingen[$i]);
    array_push($images, $img);
}
```

Here is an alternative way. Choose which ever they do the same job.

```
$images = array();
foreach ($afbeeldingen as $img) {
    array_push($images, array("src" => $img));
}
```

Use this to create your images array. Then set the value of images in `prod_data` to the images array created.

```
'images'        =>  $images
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out, I tried this option before but it didn't work at first. After some more research I found out that I wasn't using the global variable in my function!